# Accessing package root directory from sub-package

Tags: python, configuration, package, setup.py

I'm looking for the best way to access the root directory of a sub-package in order to retrieve common configuration files (which in my case are JSON files).

As an example, the directory structure may look as follows:

```
| README
| setup.py
| proj_name
   | __init__.py
   | pack_01
      | __init__.py
      | file_01.py
      | file_02.py
   | pack_02
      | __init__.py
      | file_03.py
      | file_04.py
   | conf
      | conf_01.json
      | conf_02.json
      | conf_03.json
```

In this example, the package config files are in the `proj_name/conf` directory.

When importing say `file_01` using a command such as `import proj_name.pack_01.file_01`, the attribute `__file__` would point to `proj_name/pack_01/file_01.py` and a line such as `root_dir=dirname(dirname(__file__))` is required; this however implies a knowledge of the directory structure when writing the sub-package.

Is there a way to access the root package (proj_name in this case) and its directory using a variable such as `__root_package__` or something similar? What is the tidiest way to achieve this in python? And would the method still work when building an egg using a setup.py utility?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not make `conf` a module, and have the code for interpreting the JSON files in it? Then you can easily `import` the results; exposing them via Python objects rather than as text files.

Comment: `os.path.dirname(proj_name.__file__)` should do it.

Comment: @johnsharpe well... at the moment I've got the loading and parsing functionalities in another sub-package; besides, I would like to be able to install the configuration files in a separate directory when installing the project (say `~/.package.d/config` if installing only in the user home directory)

Comment: @tdelaney: yes, but that forces me to add a line such as `import proj_name`?